# Post the full related object in ng-admin

Tags: json, angular, post, ng-admin

There's a way to post the full related object? For example, I need a full post object when a post a comment, not just the post id:

Instead of:

```
{
   comment_id: 1,
   text: "my comment",
   post: 1
}
```

I need:

```
{
   comment_id: 1,
   text: "my comment",
   post: {
      post_id: 1,
      title: "Post Title"
   } 
}
```

Comment: unclear what you are asking.

Comment: My problem is ng-admin reference field. In the example above, I'm creating a Comment object, referencing a Post object. When a click "Save", the Json sent to the server is like the first one above. I need it to send like the second.

Comment: After a while, a moved to admin-on-rest, a ReactJS encarnation of ng-admin. This question can be closed.